# Clicked legend should show remaining all legend should hide automatically in chart using highchart.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, highcharts

I am having 10 legends in highchart,if I click first legend only clicked legend should show remaining all legend should hide automatically...

Here is code with two legends

```js
$(function() {
  var chart = $('#container').highcharts({

    legend: {
      enabled: true
    },

    xAxis: {
      categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },

    series: [{
      data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
    }, {
      data: [144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4, 29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2]
    }]
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="height: 400px"></div>
```

Comment: wot.............

Comment: Hi Joe,..only clicked legend series should  show remaining series in highchart  should hide automatically..

Comment: I have no idea what you mean, can you post code and give us an idea what you want

Comment: var chart = Highcharts.chart('container', {

    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
    }, {
        data: [129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4, 29.9, 71.5, 106.4]
    }]
});


// the button action
var $button = $('#button');
$button.click(function (d) {
                        chart.hide();
                        chart.show(d); 
});

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/c2L5K/94/

Comment: adjust your question and  format the code explain simply what you want

Answer (score 3):

You need to add a legendItemClick event on the series, which will show/hide the respective series when clicked.

```
plotOptions: {
    series: {
        events: {
            legendItemClick: function (event) {
                var sr = this.chart.series;
                for(i = 0; i < sr.length; i++) {
                    if(this == sr[i])
                        sr[i].setVisible(true);
                    else
                        sr[i].setVisible(false);
                }
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Find the modified code here: [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c2L5K/106/)

Answer (score 1):

```
var alias = this;
        series: {
      events: {
          legendItemClick: function (event) {
              var sr = this.chart.series;
              for(var i = 0; i < sr.length; i++) {
                 sr[i].setVisible(false, false);
                  if(this == sr[i])
                  {
                    if(alias.selectedLines.indexOf(this) != -1){
                      alias.selectedLines.splice(alias.selectedLines.indexOf(this), 1);
                    }
                    else{
                      alias.selectedLines.push(sr[i])
                    } 
                  }
              }
              for(var i = 0; i < alias.selectedLines.length; i++) {
                alias.selectedLines[i].setVisible(true, false);
              }
              this.chart.redraw()
              return false;
          }
      }
  }
```

Here i am creating a array called selectedLines which contains all the selected legends.

variable sr contains series, we are looping through it to find a legend user just clicked. If selected legend is already present in selectedLines then we are removing from the array. that is clicking on it 2nd time will deselect it.

if legend is not already present then we push it to SelectedLines array.
Now selectedLines array has all the legends clicked my user.

We have already hidden all the legends so we just run another loop through selectedLines to show only selected legends.

This functionality enables user to click on legends they wanna view one after the other, remaining will be hidden.

PS: I have used setVisible(false, false) instead of hide() because hide() redraw every-time, instead setVisible(false, false) will not. At the end we invoke redraw() to update DOM.

Comment: Please explain bit more about the answer to understanding more easily.

Comment: @TheParam explanation Added